# Can't get transform_filter to work in Altair

Tags: altair, vega-lite

For my teaching notes I am trying to implement [this](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) vega-lite example in Altair:

```js
{
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "layer": [{
    "params": [{
      "name": "brush",
      "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}
    }],
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "timeUnit": "month",
        "field": "date",
        "type": "ordinal"
      },
      "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": "precipitation",
        "type": "quantitative"
      },
      "opacity": {
        "condition": {
          "param": "brush", "value": 1
        },
        "value": 0.7
      }
    }
  }, {
    "transform": [{
      "filter": {"param": "brush"}
    }],
    "mark": "rule",
    "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": "precipitation",
        "type": "quantitative"
      },
      "color": {"value": "firebrick"},
      "size": {"value": 3}
    }
  }]
}
```

I getting the separate charts (bar and rule to work) was easy, but I run into issues in making `mark_rule` interactive.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


df = data.seattle_weather()
selection = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

base = alt.Chart(df).add_selection(selection)

bar_i = base.mark_bar().encode(
    x="month(date):T",
    y="mean(precipitation):Q",
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1.0), alt.value(0.7)))

rule_i = base.mark_rule().transform_filter(selection).encode(y="mean(precipitation):Q")

(bar_i + rule_i).properties(width=600)
```

The error reads

```
Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector013_scale_trigger"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the chart you're interested in creating is part of Altair's example gallery: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/selection_layer_bar_month.html

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.seattle_weather()
brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='month(date):O',
    y='mean(precipitation):Q',
    opacity=alt.condition(brush, alt.OpacityValue(1), alt.OpacityValue(0.7)),
).add_selection(
    brush
)

line = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(color='firebrick').encode(
    y='mean(precipitation):Q',
    size=alt.SizeValue(3)
).transform_filter(
    brush
)

bars + line
```

The error you're seeing comes from the fact that `base` includes the selection, and both layers are derived from `base`, so the same selection is declared twice within the single chart.

Comment: great, thanks yet again @jakevdp!